# Variable is a type, which is not valid in the given context

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an interface, called `IUser`

I have two models, `User` and `Guest` and both of them implements `IUser`

I have a class, called `CardOut` what has two properties, `Card` and `User`

Here is the constructor of the `CardOut` class:

```
public CardOut(Interfaces.IUser User, Card Card) {
    this.User = User;
    this.Card = Card;
}
```

I am getting out some rows from the database, and based on the type of a cell, I am creating a `User` or a `Guest`.

```
foreach (IDictionary<string, string> row in rows) {
    if (row["type"] == "xxx") {
        User UserValue = new User();
        UserValue.buildById(int.Parse(row["user_id"]));
    } else {
        Guest UserValue = new Guest();
        UserValue.buildById(int.Parse(row["id"]));
    }
    Card Card = new Card();
    Card.buildCardByIndex(int.Parse(row["cardindex"]));
    CardOut CardOut = new CardOut(UserValue, Card);  //Here is the error
}
```

When I want to instantiate a new `CardOut` object I am getting this error:

> Error CS0103  The name 'UserValue' does not exist in the current context

How can I solve it? I can not create it outside of the if condition, because I do not know, what class should I instantiate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Declare a variable of type `IUser` outside the `if` block, and instantiate it inside the `if` with the concrete type.

Edit: added a cast since `IUser` seems not to have a member `buildById`.

```
foreach (IDictionary<string, string> row in rows) {
    IUser UserValue;
    if (row["type"] == "xxx") {
        UserValue = new User();
        ((User)UserValue).buildById(int.Parse(row["user_id"]));
    } else {
        UserValue = new Guest();
        ((Guest)UserValue).buildById(int.Parse(row["id"]));
    }
    Card Card = new Card();
    Card.buildCardByIndex(int.Parse(row["cardindex"]));
    CardOut CardOut = new CardOut(UserValue, Card);  
}
```

Comment: The problem is that: `Error CS1061 'IUser' does not contain a definition for 'buildById'`. Why it is so obvious that `IUser`  have this method? What if `User` has, and `Guest` built by some other way?

Comment: @vaso123 then you have to cast it back, or create a temporary variable of the concrete type and then assign it to the  `IUser` variable. See my edit. But if you can change the implementation of the interface, I would add the method there.

Comment: Ok, exactly that's happend what I mentioned. I am working from two databases. The `User.buildById()` uses DB1, while `Guest.buildById()` uses DB2. Now I need to write a new method, `User.buildByDB2Id()` and this method won't be in the `Guest` class. I have access to interface.

Comment: You could create a class `DB2User` derived from `User` and override the `buildById()` method. Maybe you could also have a look at design patterns such as https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern etc.